# How to add an opening parenthesis to the WHERE clause of the query?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$this->db->where_in('k.profile1_id', $value);
 $this->db->or_where_in('k.profile2_id', $value);
 $this->db->or_where_in('k.profile3_id', $value);
```

How can I modify the above code to get an extra parenthesis after WHERE like following in the Mysql?

```
WHERE ( `k`.`profile1_id` IN ('1') OR `k`.`profile2_id` IN ('1') OR `k`.`profile3_id` IN ('1`') )
```

**I have tried :-**

```
   $this->db->group_start();
   $this->db->where_in('k.profile1_id', $value);
   $this->db->or_where_in('k.profile2_id', $value);
   $this->db->or_where_in('k.profile3_id', $value);
   $this->db->group_end();
```

**But it doesn't seem to work.**

Comment: you want this SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `k.profile1_id` IN('$value') OR `k.profile2_id` IN('$value') OR `k.profile3_id` IN('$value')?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you care? Is there something not working, then please share  more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$value = $this->db->escape($value);   
$condition = "(k.profile1_id IN ($value) or k.profile2_id IN ($value) or k.profile3_id IN ($value))";
$this->db->where($condition);
$result = $this->db->get("table_name")->result();
```

refer [this](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/queries.html) to avoid sql injection in CI as suggested in comment and [this](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data) to know more about query builder in CI.

Comment: this is not CI style.

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Comment: This is a horrible idea, as it provides a pretty good attack vector for SQL injections

Answer (score 1):

using custom string:-

```
$a = $this->db->where("(`k.profile1_id` = '$value' OR `k.profile2_id` = '$value' OR `k.profile3_id` = '$value')")->where("(`k.profile4_id` = '$value')")->get('table_name')->result_array();
```

this generates sql like this:-

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE (`k.profile1_id` = 'value' OR `k.profile2_id` = 'value' OR `k.profile3_id` = 'value') AND (`k.profile4_id` = 'value')
```

Comment: I  have a precedence issue as i also have AND condition so would to have an extra bracket next to where like this : "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE (`k.profile1_id` IN('$value') OR `k.profile2_id` IN('$value') OR `k.profile3_id` IN('$value')") AND ();

Comment: @Hello try now with updated answer & let me know what happens???.